# Billboarding in LWJGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, 2d, lwjgl

I'm making a "2.5D" game with a 3d and 2d items. I have created the 3d world and am now working on the 2d items. I've looked all over for billboarding tutorials, but none of them seemed to work (because I'm a noob and probably messed something up). All I need to know is how to set up the glTranslate and glRotate so that the next render sequence renders an object perpendicular to the plane of the camera, in other words, like 2d but in the 3d world.

Here is what I'm using:

```
GL11.glPushMatrix();
GL11.glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
GL11.glRotatef(360.0f - Player.camera.vector.x, 0, -1.0f, 0); 
GL11.glRotatef(Player.camera.vector.z, -1.0f, 0, 0);
renderDroppedItems();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are noob ,you should first learn OpenGL.There are many ways to do billboarding in OpenGL, like point sprites for example. And there are many tutorials in the Web.Which tutorials you say you have looked at? Here you should ask specific question.Don't you expect anyone here writing the whole solution for you?Do you? Here is a nice tutorial for example : http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/billboarding/index.php?billCheat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your code:

```
GL11.glRotatef(360.0f - Player.camera.vector.x, 0, -1.0f, 0);
```

it should be :

```
GL11.glRotatef(360.0f - Player.camera.vector.x, -1.0f, 0, 0);
```